# Default value given to a textfield when it is blank

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

What is the default value that a textField will be carrying when nothing is typed in it.Under the codenameone TextField API .

I am getting an exception when the user inputs nothing and clicks my submit button.Null pointer exception upon using the getText()  method to obtain the value that would have been submitted through a textfield;

[image]

The marked field is  a textfield which I am collecting values from upon clicking submit button to delete a user from my system.

Comment: show thee code allen !

Comment: Look at the stack trace of the exception, it indicates the exact line of the error

Comment: What exactly is your question? The user enters nothing and you get a NPE upon trying to use the text he entered. Where is your confusion?

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading this I think I finally understand... That's the "hint" label that you can set via `setHint()`. It's not a value and it's just there to show you what needs to go in the field.

The value of an empty field is `""` an empty string.